# guzzle, how to force content-type in a multipart/form-data

Tags: php, rest, curl, multipartform-data, guzzle

I'm new with Guzzle and I'm trying to make a REST request to sign PDF file. The provider says :

- you need to use BASIC authentication
- the request must be a POST request
- the mimetype should be multipart/form-data
- the file sent must be application/octet-stream and its name should be "file"
- the data sent must be application/json and its name should be "data"

The system returns a response which contains the signed PDF file and type is application/octet-stream

This is the code I tested with Guzzle, but the provider says that the type mime sent in application/pdf. How can I "force" the mimetype for the PDF file ?

```
$client = new Client([
    'auth' => ['login', 'password'],
    'debug' => true,
    'curl'  => [
                  CURLOPT_PROXY => '192.168.1.232',
                  CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => '8080',
                  CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => 'username:password',
             ],
]);
$boundary = 'my_custom_boundary';
$multipart = [
            [
                'name'     => 'data',
                'contents' => "{'nomDocument':'documentTest.pdf','externalid':'123456'}",
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'file',
                'contents' => fopen('documentTest.pdf', 'r'),
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/octet-stream'
            ],
        ];

$params = [
    'headers' => [
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary,
    ],
    'body' => new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\MultipartStream($multipart, $boundary),
];

try{
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://server.com/api/sendDocument', $params);
} catch (RequestException $e) {
    echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
    if ($e->hasResponse()) {
        echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the Content-Type in headers

```
$multipart = [
        [
            'name'     => 'data',
            'contents' => "{'nomDocument':'documentTest.pdf','externalid':'123456'}",
            'headers'  => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen('documentTest.pdf', 'r'),
            'headers'  => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream']
        ],
    ];
```

in [Guzzle Documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart) say that you can specify headers for every multipart data. 
If you not set header Guzzle put a Content-Type for you based on file.